Template not updating language direction when changing language
In base.html.twig, I have the following:
<html lang="{{- app.request.locale -}}" dir="{{- app.request.locale|locale_dir -}}">

Where locale_dir is a custom Twig filter that returns ltr or rtl depending on the locale. Then I have a controller with a route using /{_locale}/ as path, and a small menu with languages to change around.
If I input in the address bar https://localhost:8000/en/, I get an english page with the HTML tag as:
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

If I input in the address bar https://localhost:8000/ar/, I get an arabic page with HTML tag as:
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">

However, if I input the english page address and then use the menu to change to arabic, I get the arabic page with the HTML tag as:
<html lang="ar" dir="ltr">

And if I input the arabic page address and then use the menu to change to english, I get the english page with the HTML tag as:
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">

I've placed a log entry in my custom Twig filter, and I can tell that when changing language with the menu, my filter is getting called for the HTML tag, is returning the correct value, but the tag's dir argument isn't beeing updated.
I'm guessing Symfony doesn't really reload the all page when following a link, but rather makes some sort of Ajax call (or similar) to get the content, and updates the lang argument but not the dir argument of the HTML tag?
What am I missing?
EDIT: Just tested with fiddler open to see what happens: When changing the language using the menu, fiddler detects a normal GET request with the full page as a response. And in that response, the dir argument has always the correct value:
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

and
<html lang="ar" dir="rtl">

However, the DOM itself doesn't update the dir argument as expected:
<html lang="ar" dir="ltr">

EDIT 2 Here's video of what I mean by symfony updates the body and lang argument but leaves the dir argument with it's first value

As I said, I confirmed in fiddler that the response from the server comes with the correct value in dir
EDIT 3: created a git repo with minimal testing at https://github.com/537mfb/dir_test

Your question is confusing. I have no idea what is going right or wrong. "[...] and in that response, the dir argument has always the correct value". So it's working? Symfony nor twig has anything to do with the DOM. It just generates output, in this case HTML. You are stating it wouldn't work navigating from your menu, but that's just another GET request, unless you are using JavaScript to overrule this, but nothing is mentioned about this.

Basically my code generstes the HTML correctly but symfony doesnt update the dom - i suspect when clicking a link an Ajax call is made and from the result of that call the body is replaced and so is the lang argument of HTML tag but not the dir argument

You can actually see this happen from the inspector

Symfony has nothing to do with the DOM, as already mentioned. What do you mean suspect? Is it or isn't an AJAX call? If so, then your question is incomplete and you should debug why the proper variable isn't being set. The question is lacking details at this point

@DarkBee this is a new project - it must be Symfony doing this - And I suspect because I don't know the innards of Symfony - what I know is that when I click a link theres a GET call going from the client to the server, the server respondes with a full page that has the correct dir value - but as you can see from the GIF I've added the lang argument get's updated a long with the body - but dir argument remains what it was before

An ajax or ajax like call is my best guess

Well, you'll have to figure out where that call is triggered in order to further debug the issue

@DarkBee I created a minimal test at https://github.com/537mfb/dir_test - I added 0 lines of javascript in this and it still happens - Like I said, whatever is going on comes from symfony - but I don't know enough about the innards of symfony to figure it out

@DarkBee have you got any pointers on what I found and posted as answer?

I've solved this by adding an extra entrypoint in importmap.php that I use exclusivelly on rtl languages.
EDIT: After further inspection I've realized that now with the new entrypoint added, there are two consecutive GET requests beeing performed now.
The differences in the headers of the two requests are:
Request 1:
accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml
x-sec-purpose: prefetch
x-turbo-request-id: 701c1632-41bd-4694-a309-e937451645ed
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty

Request 2:
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document

So I'm guessing @hotwired/turbo (wich comes installed with symfony's full install - using --webapp) is responsable for the issue I was seeing.
still - not ideal to have 2 GET requests - both returning the full page, but at least it's working.
